# How do I add a prefab to another prefab?

Tags: unity

I want to instantiate a prefab, and then instantiate another prefab and then set the second prefab to the first prefab.

However, this doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
    //instantiate a new weapon prefab
    Transform nNewInstantiatedPrefab = Instantiate(tPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    if (nNewInstantiatedPrefab == null)
    {
        Debug.Break();
    }

    //instantiate a new amount info canvas
    GameObject nNewAmount = Instantiate(ItemInfoCanvasPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    if (nNewAmount == null)
    {
        Debug.Break();
    }
    nNewAmount.transform.SetParent(nNewInstantiatedPrefab);

    //now test if the prefab has been attached to the other prefab:
    Transform nTest = Helpers.GoFromName(nNewInstantiatedPrefab, "AmountCanvas");
    if (nTest == null)
    {
        Debug.Break();//this line is called
    }
```

And this is the helper function. I haven't had any problems with it so far:

```
public static Transform GoFromName(Transform t, string uName)
{
    foreach (Transform g in t)
    {
        if (g.name == uName)
        {
            return g;
        }
    }
    Debug.Break();
    return null;
}
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, and perhaps prefabs can't be added to other prefabs?

Thank you!

Comment: The code looks fine. However, normally Unity attaches a `(clone)` suffix to the name of instantiated prefabs (i.e. the name of the instantiated prefab is `AmountCanvas (clone)`), and your code does not account for this. You can confirm if this is the case by checking the hierarchy window in the Unity Editor.

Comment: @Chaosed0 Thank you!! The "(Clone)" was actually the problem! Could you please make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problems instantiating prefabs and parenting them to other instantiated prefabs. At runtime, instantiated prefabs do not keep a reference back to the original prefab; they end up like any other normal `GameObject`.

The problem is that your code does not account for the `(Clone)` suffix that Unity automatically adds onto instantiated prefabs. To easily fix this, you can instead search for `AmountCanvas(Clone)` in your code.

However, I would suggest that you don't search by name at all. If you spawn multiple of the same prefab, or if there's already an instance with the name `AmountCanvas(Clone)`, you'll end up with something named `AmountCanvas(Clone) (2)` and your code will break again. You already have a reference there - `nNewAmount` - so I'd suggest passing that to whatever needs a reference to the new instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! For me, Unity names it "TheName(Clone)", without space and with an uppercase C.

Answer (score 1):

pass the parent into the instantiate call and see if it works correctly

```
GameObject nNewAmount = Instantiate(ItemInfoCanvasPrefab,nNewInstantiatedPrefab);
```

or if you must pass in the two other parameters with the parent you can add it at the end

```
 GameObject nNewAmount = Instantiate(ItemInfoCanvasPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, nNewInstantiatedPrefab);
```

if you rename the Instantiated object each time and parent to the last you would have something like this.[image]

now if you wanted to re-create or update a new prefab from a old one you can use the editors prefab utility class but will need to first Unload it then update and resave.

```
UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance();
UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.SavePrefabAsset();
```